# Nodes with relationship to multiple nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to get the Persons that know everyone in a group of persons which know some specific places.
This:

```
MATCH (:Place {name:'Breiter Weg'})<-[:knows]-(b:Person)-[:knows]->(:Place   {name:'Buchhandel'})
WITH collect(DISTINCT b) as persons
Match (a:Person)
WHERE ALL(b in persons WHERE (a)-[:knows]->(b))
RETURN a
```

works, but for the second part does a full nodelabelscan, before applying the where clause, which is extremely slow - in a bigger db it takes 8~9 seconds. I also tried this:

```
MATCH (:Place {name:'Breiter Weg'})<-[:knows]-(b:Person)-[:knows]->(:Place {name:'Buchhandel'})
Match (a:Person)-[:knows]->(b)
RETURN a
```

This only needs 2ms, however it returns all persons that know any person of group b, instead of those that know everyone.

So my question is: Is there a effective/fast query to get what i want?

Answer (score 0):

We have a [knowledge base article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/) for this kind of query that show a few approaches.

One of these is to match to :Persons known by the group, and then count the number of times each of those persons shows up in the results. Provided there aren't multiple :knows relationships between the same two people, if the count is equal to the collection of people from your first match, then that person must know all of the people in the collection.

```
MATCH (:Place {name:'Breiter Weg'})<-[:knows]-(b:Person)-[:knows]->(:Place {name:'Buchhandel'})
WITH collect(b) as persons
UNWIND persons as b // so we have the entire list of persons along with each person
WITH size(persons) as total, b
MATCH (a:Person)-[:knows]->(b)
WITH total, a, count(a) as knownCount
WHERE total = knownCount
RETURN a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler Cypher query that also compares counts -- the same basic idea used by @InverseFalcon.

```
MATCH (:Place {name:'Breiter Weg'})<-[:knows]-(b:Person)-[:knows]->(:Place {name:'Buchhandel'}), (a:Person)-[:knows]->(b)
WITH COLLECT({a:a, b:b}) as data, COUNT(DISTINCT b) AS total
UNWIND data AS d
WITH total, d.a AS a, COUNT(d.b) AS bCount
WHERE total = bCount
RETURN a
```